# How is strong induction recursive?

Tags: logic, computability

I know that strong induction is equivalent to induction, and I know that functions that are defined by inductions are recursive.

So theoretically, strong induction should also give a recursive definition (or even primitive-recursive?).

Suppose that I want to define a set of numbers by strong induction, for example: for all $i$, $2^i\in A$; and if $j,k\in A$ then $2^j3^k\in A$.

How can I show that such $A$ is recursive?

EDIT: I am generally trying to understand how Godel coding works. The definitions usually go about assigning the symbols numbers and then skipping over the part where the set of terms/formulas is recursive; or we define something like the above, for example $\#(r+t)=2^23^{\#r}5^{\#t}$, which is essentially a strong induction argument.

Comment: Is there a nonempty base you want to use for $A$?

Comment: You don't define functions by "induction" but recursively or by recursion.

Comment: @hardmath: I meant just $2^i$, otherwise it is trivial. I have added this to the question. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't your set $A$ empty?  Otherwise it has a least element, $k = 2^i3^j$ where $i,j \in A$.  By arithmetic $i , j \leq k$, but by choice of $k$ we have $k \leq i,j$.  Thus $k = 2^k3^k$ which is absurd.

Comment: @Arthur: Well, $2\in A$, therefore $3^2\in A$, therefore $2^93^9\in A$ and so on. But the particular $A$ is irrelevant. I am trying to understand how Godel coding works, because everything I saw until now was using strong induction rather than induction.

Comment: You probably just have to be a bit more precise about the definition of the set $A$.  Something along the lines of (1) every number of the form $3^i$ belongs to $A$; (2) if $i,j \in A$, then $2^i3^j$ belongs to $A$; (3) a number belongs to $A$ iff it can be shown to belong to $A$ by (repeated) applications of (1) and (2).

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, that is what I meant to write. But again, this is a less relevant example here. Is there a particularly understandable way to answer my question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to show that your $A$ is (primitive) recursive depends on what tools you have available.  I'll assume you know about primitive recursion, that you have primitive recursive coding and decoding functions for finite sequences, and that you know that exponentiation is primitive recursive.  Then you can define, by primitive recursion, a function $F$ such that $F(n)$ codes the initial segment of length $n$ of the characteristic function of your $A$.  $F(0)$ is the code of the empty sequence.  $F(n+1)$ is the (code of the result of) result of appending to (the sequence coded by) $F(n)$ a single number $q$, which is $1$ in two situations: (i) if $n$ is of the form $3^i$ or (ii) if $n$ is of the form $2^i3^j$ and $F(n)$ had $1$'s in positions $i$ and $j$; in all other situations, $q$ is $0$.  Once you have $F$, you obtain $A$ as the set of $n$ such that the last component (the component in position $n$) of $F(n+1)$ is $1$.

Comment: So how can I determine whether or not $k=\#(r+s)$?

Comment: Ah! I got it. By defining the approximations of the characteristics function of $A$, we can use bounded minimization to ask whether a particular number is in $A$ or not. ($k$ is in the domain of $F(2^k)$, and exponentiation is recursive...)

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is a little bit self-contradictory, as $3 \in A$, but $3 \ne 2^i 3^j$, unless $0 \in A$, which it doesn't seem to be.   A better definition might be: Let $A$ be the smallest set if integers such that $3^i \in A$ for every $i$ and $2^i3^j \in A$ for all $i,j \in A$    Now it's clear that $A$ is well defined, and it's also clear that $A$ is recursively enumerable, because we can easily write a computer program to list all the elements of it.   To show it's recursive, we need an algorithm to determine if $n \in A$ for a given n.

Here's one way you could do it.  Given $n$, let $n = 2^i3^jm$, where $m$ is not divisible by 2 or 3.   If $m \ne 1$ then $n \notin A$. If $j = 0$ then $n \in A$, otherwise recursively check to see if $i,j \in A$.  If they are then $n \in A$.  The algorithm will terminate because $i,j \lt n$

Comment: You forgot a check  "If $m>1$ then $n\notin A$".

Comment: I updated the definition of $A$.

Comment: @hagen, thanks.